# Can't make empty space with . in grid-template-areas

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to make empty spaces in the header.
So, I wrote code like this.

```css
header {
  grid-area: header;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: xxx-large;
  padding-top: 40px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #222;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    ".      header  header  ."
    "aside  section section section"
    "footer footer  footer  footer";
}
```

I hoped the dot section was empty.
But aside and the section below the header possess that area.

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEYrp.png)

How can I make empty spaces using grid-template-areas?

Comment: Where is your html ? ;-) Please provide all your code !

Comment: You need to show us any CSS that is relevant. Have you actually specified to aside which grid area it should go into?

Comment: **Never** mix named areas and auto-placement.

Answer (score 1):

It looks from what you have shown us as if you haven't positioned any element in the grid apart from header - this isn't enough. grid will use any empty spaces it can for any element that doesn't have a specific positioning.

```css
header {
  grid-area: header;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: xxx-large;
  padding-top: 40px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #222;
  background: magenta;
}

aside {
  grid-area: aside;
  background: yellow;
}

section {
  grid-area: section;
  background: lime;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: cyan;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: ".      header  header  ." "aside  section section section" "footer footer  footer  footer";
}
```

```html
<header>HEADER</header>
<aside>ASIDE</aside>
<section>SECTION</section>
<footer>FOOTER</footer>
```

I have given each element a background color to make it clearer what area is being used by which.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Hi jimin you can use for this on body after display:grid type justify-content:space-between ok if dont run code let me to help you ok have nice day goodbye

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).